# Network Communication Design Patterns

Tags: design-patterns, network-programming, network-protocols

I've come to realize that several questions I asked in the past, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622735/how-have-you-structured-your-network-oriented-apps) really boil down to a more fundamental question.

Are there any well known design patterns for network communications and by virtue of it's nature, protocol construction/parsing?  A google search has not revealed much.

Note that i'm not looking for solutions for any given problem, i'm looking for documented design patterns dealing with network communications and their protocols.

EDIT:

Please, don't suggest various implementation details or discuss specific protocols unless it's tied to a design pattern.  Protocol design is not the issue, it's the design patterns for creating or parsing protocols that i'm looking for, not to mention the communication patterns themselves.

EDIT2:

I find it hard to believe that nobody has come up with any common patterns for network communication.  Yes, I know "it depends", but you can say that about any project, yet there are lots of patterns that cover general ideas.

Comment: Hi, I was trying to ask similar question, and I found your question. I have developed numerous applications where there is listener thread, and client on every node. As you said, different applications can have different needs. Some might require ACK, some may rely on duplicate messages etc. While developing, most of the times I look back at my previous code or go with what feels like the most logical way of doing something. It would be really helpful, if there were any patterns, that talk about application layer communication Or should one just look at existing protocols, to find solutions?

Comment: Check out also Proactor / Reactor patterns. Here is an article for example: [http://www.artima.com/articles/io_design_patterns.html](http://www.artima.com/articles/io_design_patterns.html)

Comment: @casperOne - What is the purpose of closing a 3 year old question that is already answered?

Comment: @MystereMan The age of the post doesn't matter, if it's not *currently* suitable for the site, then it gets closed.  If you disagree with the closing, feel free to bring it up on [Meta].

Comment: this: (http://www.amazon.com/Pattern-Oriented-Software-Architecture-Volume-Patterns/dp/0471958697) has been around for a while. there is a second volume

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say that the chain of responsability pattern could be usefull to send/receive data from/to the network.

You build a series of commands to send to the server from the client.
Each command is processed through the chain of responsability, with data added to handle the command correctly.

On data send, the chain could look like that

```
Command   --> Wrap some       --> Encrypt --> Send data
to send       data around 
              the command 
              (source, extra 
              information if 
              needed)
```

On data receive, the chain could be similar, but the other way around

```
Receive Data  -->  Decrypt --> Unwrap extra data --> Execute command
```

You can check this article for more informations about the chain of responsability.
http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/chain.html

Answer (score 14):

This is a pretty broad question and its treatment likely requires a fairly dense book.

I don't know of any such resource myself, but lets think this through and consider what would be the dimensions of a network communication pattern space:

connection modality:    { connection-based, connection-less}

interaction modality:  { synchronous, asynchronous }

conversation complexity: { command-response, dialog}

message form: { freeform-stream, semi-structured block, fully-structured block }
..?

A good place to start is to take the TCP/IP family of protocols, map them to the above space, and take a look at the implementation(s) of one or more specimens that occupy a unique position in the above protocol-characteristics pattern space.  Source code of your favorite *nix os would be a good place to look.

Parser implementations would probably fall into two broad categories:  {command-switched processing, finite-state-machine}.

The former is (obviously) the simpler of the two and likely the initial implementation (unless you've done this sort of thing before).

The latter is (likely) more robust, efficient (in terms of loc), and would allow for adopting changes to a protocol (if it is still subject to design change).

(The underlying (virtual) OS networking facilities (of course) also greatly influence the implementation.  Take JVM, for example:  NIO selection based channel processing would work quite nicely with a FSM.)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend: abstract away the network protocol/s.

First decide what are the functionality, the modules and the APIs between them. Then decide what protocol is the data going to ride across the network.

Then carefully encapsulate all the network issues in their own layer so you can later apply encryption, compression, add http transport (to pass firewalls) or whatever you want to add later in a manner orthogonal to functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Acceptor/Connector pattern : http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/Acceptor.pdf

Chain of filters base on Gof Chain Of responsabiliy, it's used in a lot of network stack/framework.

State machines for encoding/decoding PDUs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about design patterns, but researching existing protocols is probably a good starting point, especially "modern" ones that have been standardized.

BitTorrent is a highly popular decentralized protocol that has a number of extensions.

OpenSSH is another good candidate; it supports feature negotiation, multiple encryption types, and de/muxing channels.

VoIP protocols are good for streaming applications: RTP and H.323

Network routing protocols are good as well: BGP (and extensions), LDP, VRRP/CARP.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about patterns, as such, but there's a few "obvious" selection points.
First, do you want to use ASN.1 or not (this influences a WHOLE lot)?
Second, do you want a human-readable protocol or a binary one?
Third, do you want any security aspects in your protocol?

Not that answering "want to use ASN.1" will force teh answer to quite a few of the protocol design questions.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't gone through this thoroughly, but I guess [this](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/acceptor-patterns4.pdf) is good doc:

Also, [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521790409) looks like a good book: